# What does this different formatting style in the questions list mean?

Tags: discussion, design

I have seen few questions being shown with a different background colour in the questions list, but only in stackoverflow:

[image]
What does the different background in some questions mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The background coloring indicates that post contains one of your favorite tags.

The "interesting" tab is unique to Stack Overflow.